# PhoneGap command not recognized

Tags: command-line, cordova, command

I have followed the directions on PhoneGap's website and installed PhoneGap using the command prompt on Windows.  However, after it has installed I try to run the command 'phonegap' and I get an error saying that ***'phonegap' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.  How do I fix this?*** Thanks.

Comment: Set your path as mentioned in AnriDat's answer. If you don't know how to do this then google how to change path in windows. Make sure you don't overwrite any part of the path that already exists before you change it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try to run CMD as administrator. Hopefully that will solve your problem. This solved mine.

Answer (score 4):

You might need to add phonegap to your classpath variable, in order to let the prompt know where the phonegap .exe file is located.

Try writing the full path of the exe file, if that runs, then what I mentioned above should solve your problem.

EDIT
Just looked at the install page at phonegap.com (http://phonegap.com/install/). Very scarce on the information I would say.. But I still recommend investigating the above.

Answer (score 3):

The Problem with enthronement variable for default path of your your current user. Follow the steps.

Click the Start menu and type "regedit" on the search box. This will launch the Windows Registry Editor program.

Enter to the following Registry entry: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows Script Host\Settings

Select the "Enabled" entry in the right side window. If this entry is there, right-click and select "New" followed by "DWORD Value." Name the value "Enabled."
Right-click the "Enabled" entry and click "Modify."
Change the number in the "Value" box to "1." This will re-enable WSH.
close all opened cmd windows and open a new window.

Comment: Very helpful. It works even when reputation is 0. Mark it as answer please.

Answer (score 2):

Even though this is a very old question, I'm going to post a solution that worked for me on Windows Vista/7/8. The problem is that by default the command prompt in which the npm command is run is not elevated. So launch a command prompt as administrator and then run npm command. If it is not elevated then the environment variables wont be set properly.

Answer (score 2):

In windows 7 platform, when the latest version of phonegap (3.4) installed it hosts in path like this:

C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\npm

Sometimes you should add this address to the **PATH** environment manually.

Go to System Properties-> Advanced -> Environment Variables
Select **PATH** variable from list and then edit it